# how to set $.getJSON timeout to indefinite

Tags: jquery

how to set $.getJSON timeout to indefinite

browser sets a default timeout of 20 secs but i want it indefinite for long polling

Comment: You should actually use timeouts of around 30 seconds to a minute because the connection may be cut somewhere in the network. You should set a timeout and prepare your client and server for re-polling the data.

Comment: You should prepare your client and server for re-polling the data anyway because of the multitude of errors which may occur.

Answer (score 4):

Use jQuery.ajaxSetup and the timeout setting:

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. [..] The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  timeout: 0
});
```

Comment: Specifying `timeout: 0` will disable the timeout completely.

Comment: Thanks Barmar I will add this.

Comment: i've added this.. in i.e. 7, still the request timeout.. also in FF3.0.15

Comment: Maybe this is caused by a server timeout setting.